# Pixel format for OpenGL 4.3

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create a rendering context for OpenGL 4.3.
I've created a temporary rendering context in order to load all the extensions and then destroyed this temporary rendering context and it works, all the features are loaded.

Now I have to create the final rendering context but it seems I can't find a good pixel format.

This is the function I use to try to find the pixel format and create the final rendering context:

```
int attributeListInt[19];
int pixelFormat[20];
unsigned int formatCount;
int result;
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pixelFormatDescriptor;
int attributeList[5];
float fieldOfView, screenAspect;
char *vendorString, *rendererString;

m_hDeviceContext = GetDC(m_hWnd);
if (!m_hDeviceContext)
    return false;

attributeListInt[0] = WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB;
attributeListInt[1] = TRUE;

attributeListInt[2] = WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB;
attributeListInt[3] = TRUE;

attributeListInt[4] = WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB;
attributeListInt[5] = WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB;

attributeListInt[6] = WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB;
attributeListInt[7] = 32;

attributeListInt[8] = WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB;
attributeListInt[9] = 24;

attributeListInt[10] = WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB;
attributeListInt[11] = TRUE;

attributeListInt[12] = WGL_SWAP_METHOD_ARB;
attributeListInt[13] = WGL_SWAP_EXCHANGE_ARB;

attributeListInt[14] = WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB;
attributeListInt[15] = WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB;

attributeListInt[16] = WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB;
attributeListInt[17] = 8;

attributeListInt[18] = 0;

result = wglChoosePixelFormatARB(m_hDeviceContext, attributeListInt, NULL, 20, pixelFormat, &formatCount);
if (result != 1)
    return false;

bool bCreatedSuccessfully = false;

for (int i = 0; i < formatCount && !bCreatedSuccessfully; i++)
{
    result = SetPixelFormat(m_hDeviceContext, pixelFormat[i], &pixelFormatDescriptor);

    if (result == 1)
        bCreatedSuccessfully = true;
}

if (!bCreatedSuccessfully)
    return false;

if (m_bOpenGL43)
{
    attributeList[0] = WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB;
    attributeList[1] = 4;
    attributeList[2] = WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB;
    attributeList[3] = 3;
}
else
{
    attributeList[0] = WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB;
    attributeList[1] = 3;
    attributeList[2] = WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB;
    attributeList[3] = 3;
}

attributeList[4] = 0;

m_hRenderingContext = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(m_hDeviceContext, 0, attributeList);
if (m_hRenderingContext == NULL)
    return false;

result = wglMakeCurrent(m_hDeviceContext, m_hRenderingContext);
if (result != 1)
    return false;

glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

if (bVSyncEnalbed)
    result = wglSwapIntervalEXT(1);
else
    result = wglSwapIntervalEXT(0);

if (result != 1)
    return false;

m_bInitialized = true;

return true;
```

My problem is that wglChoosePixelFormatARB returns 10 avaiable pixel formats, but none of them seems to be right because SetPixelFormat always return FALSE.

Any idea?

Comment: Try 24 for `WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB`. This is the total count of only the RGB components. So for 8 bits per color component, the value should be 24. If you want alpha as well, there's a separate `WGL_ALPHA_BITS_ARB` value for that.

Comment: And, maybe try getting rid of `WGL_SWAP_METHOD_ARB`. You should be able to rely on it choosing whatever swap method is best.

Comment: I tryed both removin `WGL_SWAP_METHOD_ARB` and setting 24 for `WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB` but still nothing. The only thing changed is that now wglChoosePixelFormatARB is returning 20 pixel formats instead of 10.

Comment: I had problems with WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB on some platform.

Comment: Ok I've found the solution. When I created the temparary rendering context in order to load OpenGL 4.3, I was setting up the pixel format for the same window I was really trying to create the rendering context. So I just loaded the extensions in a temporary window as well and it's all working fine.